# How to change the tag when creating a class

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

so, when someone creates a subclass of something in Protegé, this is what comes out of It:

```
:Wedding rdf:type owl:Class
     rdfs:subClassOf bruh:Event
```

Given that "*bruh*" is a prefix that I have instanciated, because of an ontology that I am reusing. How can I do something more like this:

```
:Wedding rdf:type bruh:Ocurrence
     rdfs:subClassOf bruh:Event
```

Since "Occurence" is a class that I am reusing? It's not the same as creating instances, right?

Comment: OWL 2 DL allows [Punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning).
It is possible to have `:Wedding` as `owl:Class` and `bruh:Ocurrence` at the same time: there would be two axioms - class-declaration and class-assertion (and named-individual-declaration optionally).

Comment: Thanks, I will try doing that.

Comment: @ssz How would named-individual-declaration work in that case? Let's say, If I want to create an individual for somebody's specific Wedding?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
:Wedding rdf:type bruh:Ocurrence
```

This is the declaration of an instance, with IRI `:Wedding`.

```
:Wedding rdf:type owl:Class
```

This is the declaration of a class, with IRI `:Wedding`.

This is called punning (i.e., using the same IRI for different categories of entities. As mentioned by @ssz in the comment, this is allowed in OWL 2 DL (classes and individuals can share an IRI, but not properties - a data property and an object property cannot share an IRI, this would make the ontology OWL 2 Full).

However, you should expect these to appear as separate axioms (the subclassof property won't appear on the XML element describing the instance, it will appear on the class).

Note that punned individuals and classes are not related logically, they just happen to have the same name. So, it is important to know why you wish to pun them - you're not mentioning this in the question, so I wonder if you are trying to pun the entities or just trying to describe one of the two - the class or the individual.